# UITableView sections from JSON data swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have JSON data like this:

```
[{"name":"Rice","Menu":{"title":"titl1"}},{"name":"Name2","Menu":{"title":"title2"}}]
```

I want to build a table view with a section for each pair [id, name]. The section title should be the menu title, the only cell for each section should be the name value.

How can I parse the JSON data into an array and use  in order to array.count determine how many section have to be displayed?

**EDIT**

```
class Menus {
   private var _name:String!
   private var _title:String!

   var name:String {
      return _name
   }

   var title:String {
      return _title
   }

   init(nam:String, title:String) {
      _name = nam
      _title = title
   }
}
```

**NEW EDIT**

```
x.forEach {
   if let uw = ($0["name"]).string {
      um.insert(uw)
      if let hru = ($0["Menu"]["title"]).string {
         us.insert(hru)
      }
   }
}

for i in um {
   for u in us {
      var men = Menus(nam: i, tit: u)
      self.menus.append(men)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arrData:[[String:AnyObject]]! = [
    ["name":"Rice",
        "Menu":
            [
                "title":"titl1"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "name":"Name2",
        "Menu":
            [
                "title":"title2"
        ]
    ]
]

var arrMenu:[Menus]! = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0..<arrData.count {
        let dish = arrData[i]
        let menu = dish["Menu"] as! [String:String]

        let name = dish["name"] as! String
        let title = menu["title"]

        arrMenu.append(Menus.init(nam: name, title: title!))
    }


}
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return arrMenu.count
}

override func tableView( tableView :UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String{
    let menu:Menus = arrMenu[section]
    return menu.name
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let menu = arrMenu[indexPath.section]

    cell.textLabel?.text = menu.title

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Grracias i will try it

Comment: I want to use a model `Menu` can i use that?

Comment: `var menus = [Menus]()`

Comment: Thank you so much i will check this out

Comment: How do i save the json data into `arrData`

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: show the code where you receive JSON, i meant your API response code.

Comment: http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cglYYtlZcO?indent=2 Am getting the `Items` key...the menu inside is where i set title

Comment: Inside viewDidLoad

Comment: Hey @ Mr.Bista , i found this really useful , im just wondering what the sections  in this case , would be and where its made ?